# Javafx Titlepane with min height

Tags: javafx

How can i make a javafx titlepane show some content when it's colapsed?
I've done something similar in wpf:

[image: Expanders in WPF]

Comment: Add the title pane to a VBox and add another pane below the title pane

Comment: as with everything that's not supported you'll have to do it yourself ;) Done cleanly is most probably nothing you would get from this site because it requires real work to implement a new control - which basically is what you are asking. That said: you might want to have a look at its skin, maybe it's possible to enhance the semantics of collapsed/expanded to partially-expanded.

Answer (score 0):

It'll be helpful if you can share some code to show what you're trying to do.

`TitledPane` accepts a `title`

```
TitledPane tp = new TitledPane(title, content);
```

OR

```
tp.textProperty().set(title)
```

that, when set, shows up even when the node is collapsed.

Also, `TitledPane` is mostly used with an `Accordion`, which handles the expand/collapse UI semantics. The only caveat drawback in Accordion being that you can only have one TitledPane expanded at one time.

Comment: All i want is something like in the picture, there i have some expanders (TitlePane in javafx), the first 2 are collapsed but i can still see some content, in this case some buttons.
I want the expander to show part of their content if its collapsed, the Pane part of the TitlePane.